# fixed floating action button in fragment

Tags: android, floating-action-button

i have fab and i want fixed on position end|right|bottom .
but in my fragment it hide and show with scroll recycler .
and not show all fab in fragment because i use tab and toolbar.
please help?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.example.hadi.music.fragment.ListStoryFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rec_view_story"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_plus"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

Comment: Is this your entire layout code?

Comment: yes it is my layout

Answer (score 0):

Remove 2 lines `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` and 
    `android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"`

Comment: not work it hide and show when scroll again and not show all fab

Answer (score 0):

Try this `xml`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/topic_list_recycler_view"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:fabSize="normal" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```